# Sqoop bulk export to SQL Server

Tags: sqoop

I'm trying to export 21046329 rows into SQL Server but it is very slow. I tried to use bulk insert but it doesn't work. Looking into SQL Server Profiler I saw that it inserts only 1 row per stmt, after that I took a look at sqoop mapper and I saw that it generates SQL queries like this

> 'org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.sqlserver.SqlServerExportBatchOutputFormat:
>   Using query INSERT INTO [test3] ([col1], [col2], [col3], [col4],
>   [col5], [col6], [col7]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'

Sqoop export command:

```
sqoop export
--connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;database=test2;EnableBulkLoad=true;BulkLoadBatchSize=100024;BulkLoadOptions=0' 
--username test --password pass --table 'test3' 
--export-dir /exportDirFromHDFS --input-lines-terminated-by "n" 
--input-fields-terminated-by ',' 
--batch -m 10
```

Does someone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the property `sqoop.export.records.per.statement` to
specify the number of records that will be used in each insert statement:

```
sqoop export \
  -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=10 \
  --connect 
  ...
```

As a result, Sqoop will create the following query:

> INSERT INTO table VALUES (...), (...), (...), ...;

Comment: I tried, it still generates like this:
org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.sqlserver.SqlServerExportBatchOutputFormat: Using query INSERT INTO [test3] ([col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)